# Sync primitives atomic package

Tags: go

Sync package in Go have Once primitive. Do() method realized that

```
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Why i cant use other version this method?

```
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if o.done == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that would read the done field concurrently without synchronization, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The [Go memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) does not guarantee that your read of `done` in `if o.done == 1` will proceed atomically. Your program's behaviour is undefined in these circumstances. There are many ways this can go wrong – for example, you may read a partial value being written out in another goroutine.

> Programs that modify data being simultaneously accessed by multiple goroutines must serialize such access.
>
> To serialize access, protect the data with channel operations or other synchronization primitives such as those in the `sync` and `sync/atomic` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Your version has a data race. The results are undefined. For example,

`racer.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

type Once struct {
    m    sync.Mutex
    done uint32
}

func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if o.done == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}

func main() {
    var once Once

    go once.Do(func() {})
    go once.Do(func() {})

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000a0008 by goroutine 6:
  main.(*Once).Do()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:15 +0x47

Previous write at 0x00c0000a0008 by goroutine 5:
  sync/atomic.StoreInt32()
      /home/peter/go/src/runtime/race_amd64.s:229 +0xb
  main.(*Once).Do()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:25 +0x9f

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:31 +0xc4

Goroutine 5 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:30 +0x96
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

See [Go: Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).